# Reference external java classes in resources.groovy

Tags: grails, resources, dependency-injection

I'm writing a grails application to display information coming from a database.
The database access is done by Spring services (with DAO, SQLJ scripts, etc.) and i'd like to use it from my grails controllers.

I've added maven dependencies to import these external Java classes.

My question is: how can i configure the resources.groovy file to be able to reference my existing spring beans from my controllers ?

This is what i tried at the moment:

```
import com.BeanClass

// Place your Spring DSL code here
beans = {
    springServiceName(BeanClass){
    }
}
```

And the service class in the external project:

```
package com;
...
@Repository("springServiceName")
@Service
public class BeanClass implements BeanInterface {
  ...
}
```

But i have the following error when i run the application:

```
[groovyc] org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
[groovyc] C:\epo\wIndigo\prs-web\grails-app\conf\spring\resources.groovy: 1: unable to resolve class com.BeanClass
```

Do you have an idea why it doesn't retrieve the sources successfully ?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Regards.

Comment: Have you added your external classes in the class path? \lib\yourservices.jar?

Comment: @Michael this is not the right approach when using Maven

Comment: Thanks @Don +1,  I'm not sure how i missed that ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've added maven dependencies to import these external Java classes.

Can you show us exactly how you did this? You should have added something like this in the `dependencies` section of `BuildConfig.groovy`

```
compile 'group-id:artifact-id:version'
```

for example, to add the Jackson library:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.7.6'
}
```

### Update

Can you verify whether you're using Maven to build, deploy, etc. your Grails app, or you just want the dependencies to be retrieved from a Maven repo?

If the latter, you can customise the Maven repositories it searches in the `repositories` section of `BuildConfig.groovy`

For example

```
repositories {

    grailsPlugins()
    grailsHome()
    grailsCentral()

    mavenLocal '/path/to/some/local/repository'
}
```

Comment: Hi Don, dependencies are declared into my pom.xml file. So i've updated the BuildConfig.groovy like that: uncomment mavenLocal() instruction in repositories section, and add dependency on my package on the dependencies section. But grails seems to be automatically configured to use maven repo under .m2 directory of user local directory. As i'm using a custom maven repo installed somewhere else, grails fails to retrieve the dependency... does something exist to configure grails to use another maven reposity ? Or maybe it's possible to make grails read the pom.xml dependecies section directly ?

Comment: Hi again, i changed my repository to point to ~/.m2/... and rebuilt all my projects so that dependency jars will be store in this repository. But even with this modification, it doesn't detect the dependencies.

Comment: Problem solved. Was about Ivy who didn't refresh its data from the real maven repository... i found nothing to fix this issue, strange. At the moment i just copy manualy my dependency jars from the maven to ivy repository.

Answer (score 0):

Couple things.

1.) Have you added your external jar to the \lib\ folder of you grails app and restarted the application.  It should work fine after you do this.

2.) Include the full class path and name in the bean definiation, use 'com.path.to.class.Bean' and not just 'Bean'.

**Also...**

If you have any @PersistanceContext in your service class don't expect grails to inject the EntityManager.  You'll have to do some extra work in you resource.xml to handle that.

Comment: kij specified the dependency using Maven so the JAR should not be added to the /lib directory